# OpenGL: Apply homographic transformation to matrix stack

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, homography

I am completely new to OpenGL and completely rusty at C++. For a school assignment, I have to modify some C++ starter code to create a rudimentary 2D animation.

I would like to transform a unit square into various trapezoids. I can compute the homographies that accomplish this but I cannot figure out how to apply them to the matrix stack.

Existing code of the form:

```
// Draw rectangle
glLoadIdentity();
glPushMatrix();
glScalef(HEIGHT, WIDTH, 1.0)
// C++ code to set colour
// C++ code to draw square
glPopMatrix()
```

draws a rectangle scaled to HEIGHT and WIDTH with the chosen colour, as expected.

One of the homographies is:

```
1.0   0.0       0.0
0.0   9.0/4.0   3.0/4.0
0.0   1.0/12.0  1.0/4.0
```

It transforms the points: (1, 1), (-1, 1), (-1, -1), (1, -1) to (3, 9), (-3, 9), (-6, -9), (6, -9) respectively.

I am representing this in column-major order as:

```
float homographyBody[9] = {1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9.0/4.0, 1.0/12.0, 0.0, 3.0/4.0, 1.0/4.0}
```

However, substituting:

```
glMultMatrixf(homographyBody)
```

for:

```
glScalef(HEIGHT, WIDTH, 1.0)
```

does not have the desired effect.

No combination of multiplication and scaling seems to be able to render anything other than a long wedge extending from a point close to the origin up and to the right.

I suspect I am simply ignorant of some basic concept. Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`glMultMatrix()` expects a 4x4 matrix as argument. Also, as you already noticed, OpenGL stores matrices in column major order.

To make this work, you'll have to extend you matrix to 4x4. You need a 4x4 matrix that transforms 3D points represented in homogenous coordinates, just like your original 3x3 matrix transforms 2D points in homogenous coordinates.

For your 3x3 matrix, the transformation is applied as:

```
[ a00 a01 a02 ]   [ x ]   [ a00 * x + a01 * y + a02 ]
[ a10 a11 a12 ] * [ y ] = [ a10 * x + a11 * y + a12 ]
[ a20 a21 a22 ]   [ 1 ]   [ a20 * x + a21 * y + a22 ]
```

From this, after division by `w` (3rd component of the resulting vector), you get the resulting point as:

```
x' = (a00 * x + a01 * y + a02) / (a20 * x + a21 * y + a22)
y' = (a10 * x + a11 * y + a12) / (a20 * x + a21 * y + a22)
```

Extending this to a 4x4 matrix, where we don't really care about the `z` coordinate:

```
[ a00 a01 0.0 a02 ]   [ x ]   [ a00 * x + a01 * y + a02 ]
[ a10 a11 0.0 a12 ] * [ y ] = [ a10 * x + a11 * y + a12 ]
[ 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 ]   [ z ]   [ z                       ]
[ a20 a21 0.0 a22 ]   [ 1 ]   [ a20 * x + a21 * y + a22 ]
```

After division by `w` (which is now the 4th component of the resulting vector), you get the same point as before.

For your example, this is:

```
float homographyBody[16] = {
    1.0f, 0.0f,      0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 9.0f/4.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f/12.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f,      1.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 3.0f/4.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f/4.0f
};
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, the extra "=" was a typo. My 3x3 matrix for the homography is in standard form, but my float array transforms this to column-major order, as stated in the OP. I can't make sense of the map from either of these orders to the one you have given for the 4x4 representation. Could you explain this mapping?

Comment: @Schemer I added some explanation.

Comment: Many thanks for explaining that.  Googling for an answer was an adventure and a half before I posted to SO.  I have applied your extended matrix and the homography is being rendered properly now.